# JScrollPane при setLayout(null)

Tags: java, swing

Не так давно задавал вопрос про ScrollPane, но, как оказалось, ответ на него проблемы не решил. Пытался создать JScrollPane для JTextArea - получается только при дефолтном setLayout или любом другом значении кроме null. Как создать его при нулевом значении?

Comment: setPrefferedWidth, setPrefferedHeigh или их аналоги для min|max не помогают? вообще если вы делаете setLayout(null) то размеры и позиции элемента задаются через setBounds

Comment: @АлександрМартынцев, проблема даже не в размерах, я думаю. Поле просто не создается, пробовал и так, и сяк, но результата нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привет!
Попробуй так (пример с прошлого ответа):

```
public class Example {
```

JTextArea incoming;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Example example= new Example ();
    example.go();
}

public void go (){
    ......
    incoming = new JTextArea(15,50);
    incoming.setLineWrap(true);

```
    incoming.setLayout(null);

incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
incoming.setEditable(false);
JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(incoming) ;
qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
```

Comment: что означают '**'?

Comment: убрал эти знаки. Они не часть кода.